# Possible CSS compatibility issue with Chrome? Maybe javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

My site: otwdrums.com

My problem: My site appears perfectly in Firefox and Safari, but in Chrome (on MY computers and a few others) it is not displaying the main image and text.  My buddy can see it on his computer using Chrome, but not on 3 of the computers I tested it on.  Also, my iPhone DOES display it correctly with the Chrome mobile browser.  Odd.

I THINK it may be a CSS issue? I'm not a developer or programmer, it's a hobby, so please forgive my naivety.

Any help??  Please?

Comment: Please try to narrow down the issue by debugging it and just don't post a link to your site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I see it correctly. But the first time it didn't show headline text for long. I guess the reason should be network speed of your site, and load the 'Open Sans' font files from your server is slow. You can consider to use the online fonts at www.google.com/fonts. And the climber.jpg costs me 3.12s to download. (the font.woff costs 1.x sec).

Comment: Try hit Ctrl+F5 on problematic computers ;)

Comment: There are any number of cross-browser compatibility issues, particularly with Internet Explorer. You'll have to be specific about which browsers work on which platform and which don't to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going out on a limb here, but I'm guessing it's because of the naming, adbox, diffrent browsers have diffrent blocks against ads therefor its hidden in some and shown on others, cause the code is there in all browsers I've tried and in thoose it hasnt been shown it has been set to be hidden by a adblocker

Comment: Just tested and my chrome doesn't work with Adblock Plus but when I turn it off it does. Awesome guess :P

Comment: yeah, you should be careful with the naming, happened myself once took me about an hour to solve it -.-